# Using pipes in a WinDBG extension

Tags: winapi, windbg

I am writing a WinDBG extension to debug a device driver, and need to call an external binary to debug the device's firmware. I would like to show the output of this binary in the WinDBG console.

My initial idea was to simply pipe the output of the binary to a buffer and print that buffer with `ControlledOutput`. However, I get a 'broken pipe' error when I try to read from the pipe in my extension.

Here is how I create the external process in my extension:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sAttr;
HANDLE childOutRead = NULL;
HANDLE childOutWrite = NULL;
PROCESS_INFORMATION childProcInfo;
STARTUPINFO childStartInfo;

char buf[4096];

sAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

CreatePipe(&childOutRead, &childOutWrite, &sAttr, 0);
// don't inherit read end
SetHandleInformation(childOutRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

ZeroMemory(&childProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&childStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

childStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
childStartInfo.hStdError = childOutWrite;
childStartInfo.hStdOut = childOutWrite;
childStartInfo.hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
childStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

CreateProcessA(NULL, "myBinary.exe someArgs", 
               NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, 
               &childStartInfo, &childProcInfo);

// close the handle not used in parent
CloseHandle(childOutWrite);

// read output
while (1) {
    DWORD read;
    BOOL r;
    DWORD error;

    r = ReadFile(childOutRead, buf, sizeof(buf), &read, NULL);
    if (!r) {
        error = GetLastError();
        windbgPrintf("got error 0x%x\n", error);
        break;
    }
    if (read == 0) break;
    windbgPrint(buf, read);
}
```

`ReadFile` fails with error `0x6D`, `BROKEN_PIPE`. This makes me suspect that the pipe is somehow not being inherited.

I have nearly identical code working in a test outside of WinDBG, so it must be doing something differently. How do I get pipes working in this way inside WinDBG?

Comment: inside or not inside windbg this is unrelated. look in child process - are pipe not closed. are child not exit..

Comment: *If an anonymous pipe is being used and the write handle has been closed*(at both sides), *when ReadFile attempts to read using the pipe's corresponding read handle, the function returns FALSE and GetLastError returns ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE*. I suggest to use named pipes or other IPCs with nonblocking-wait mode.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but try should be setting `childStartInfo.hStdInput` to something. When using `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, all 3 handles need to be specified. This is vaguely mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles#section-1) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_startupinfoa#STARTF_USESTDHANDLES). As a quick test, try `childStartInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);` and see if things get further.

Comment: @SeanCline setting the `hStdInput` handle does not change the behavior I'm seeing.